# Resque not able to load Selenium Webdriver for firefox

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium, resque

I'm getting this error while I run a worker in Resque

```
/Users/apoorvparijat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `for'
/Users/apoorvparijat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
```

The same code works fine while running independently from terminal. It opens firefox when run not as resque worker.

Is there some child process issue?

This is the line where execution is halted.

```
debugger
=> 11        @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
```

I tried setting breakpoint and checking if `selenium-webdriver` is loaded. `Selenium::Webdriver` was required. Just this line doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with `xvfb` not starting properly. Resolved now.